# Get rid of cached data in didUpdateToLocation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, gps, core-location

I'm trying to get the actual position on the iPhone Simulator. But I always get the cached result. My question is related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093919/corelocation-problem) and [this question](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/47667-didupdatetolocation-fires-cached-coordinates-un-real-timestamp.html). I'm using code from the LocateMe example:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
           fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
     NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) return;
    if (bestEffortAtLocation == nil || bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {
        self.bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;
        if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {

            [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
            locationManager.delegate = nil;

            latitude = newLocation.coordinate.latitude;
            longitude = newLocation.coordinate.longitude;
        }
    }
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work right:

```
if (locationAge > 5.0) return;
```

If the GPS coordinates are older than 5 seconds the method will return. But in my case (iPhone Simulator) the method is only called once. So exiting the method isn't a good idea here. If I extract the location at the beginning of the method I get cached results. In the code example above I never get a coordinate.

What am I missing?

**Edit 1:**

Everything works fine on iPod touch.

**Edit 2:**

How can I force the locationManager to update its location? `distanceFilter` is set to `kCLDistanceFilterNone`, but it doesn't detect that the position changed a few kilometers.

How do I know the location data is ready? E.g. the location updates are coming every 10 seconds, do I have to introduce a pause? Because my application is immediately taking the existing value and is not waiting if the locationmanager is ready.

**Edit 3:**

After about a minute I get

> Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCLErrorDomain error 0.)

I have enabled wifi and the iPod touch and the MacBook Pro is in the same SSID. What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 4:**

Seems to be a problem with Xcode 3.2.4 and iOS 4.1. See also [here](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20101002234000AA2MUhi). I'm not alone: [CLLocationManager on iPhone Simulator fails with kCLErrorDomain Code=0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3110708) (Many more results on Google)

**Edit 5:**

In iOS 4 Apple uses its own database for geolocations. But I don't understand why there is a difference between iPod and MBP.

**Edit 6:**

Localization also doesn't work on iPad. Has anyone come up with a solution?

Comment: What do you expect this line to do? "if (locationAge > 5.0) return;"

Comment: @latenitecoder: Sorry, I can't remember exactly. What I can see is that *If the GPS coordinates are older than 5 seconds the method will return*. So that I only get up to date results. But that has been a long time...

Comment: You still looking for an answer? - I just realised this is very old.

Comment: @latenitecoder: No, not anymore. But you could post your answer for others having the same problem.