# Can didUpdateLocations time out?

Tags: ios, core-location

Lets say I have everything turned on, WIFI, GPS and CELL.  However, I'm inside a subway where everyone of these are blocked.

If I do a startUpdatingLocation, would there be a time out message? And where would it come from?

(Note: I believe it will send me a previous known location, but what if it is my first time turning everything on?)

Comment: Have you read the documentation [`CLLocationManagerDelegate`](https://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/CLLocationManagerDelegate), it clearly state [`– locationManager:didFailWithError:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didFailWithError:).

Comment: I've read it, but I just want to make sure I'm not mistaken as I have no means of testing this quickly.

Comment: You can test it easily using a [Faraday cage](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13831212/1693173) to block the signals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you first send `startUpdatingLocation` your delegate will get a callback with the cached location.  You can tell its a cached location because of its [age](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3098788/1693173).  Then once it gets a fix from Cell, WiFI, and/or GPS you will get additional updates.  If it never gets a fix you'll get the `didFailWithError:` message back after a few minutes.  However, I think once you've gotten at least one fix you won't get the error if you later lose GPS/WiFi/Cell signals by going into the subway.

Comment: Ok, what happens if they don't have a cached location? I guess it goes straight to didFailWithError.

Comment: I think it will try to get a signal for a few minutes before it goes to didFailWithError:   I'm not certain it will report an error if the only problem is lack of signal, it may just keep trying.  You may want to set a timer if you want to be sure to handle this case.