# Incorrect distance and route found in my walking/running app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am working on this walking/running app which calculates distance in meters and records lat-long for further use. Now when I calculate distance I get incorrect distance every time. I have compared it with other running apps and they generally show different distance than my distance.

Here is the code that I am using:

```
#define kDesiredAccuracy 5.0f

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation;
self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kDesiredAccuracy;
_routes = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
lastKnownLocation = nil;

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    // return if accuracy is less than 0 or is greater than desired accuracy.
    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0)
    {
        return;
    }
    if(newLocation.horizontalAccuracy > kDesiredAccuracy)
    {
        return;
    }

    NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
    CLLocationSpeed speed = [newLocation speed];
    // return if stale data or user is not moving
    if (locationAge > 5.0 || speed <= 0) return;

    //return if first location is found
    if(lastKnownLocation == nil)
    {
        lastKnownLocation = newLocation;
        return;
    }

    CLLocationDistance distance = [newLocation distanceFromLocation:(self.pramDistance > 0)?lastKnownLocation:oldLocation];
    if(distance > 0)
    {
        // save distance for future use
        NSMutableDictionary *dict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"latitude"];
        [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g", newLocation.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"longtitude"];
        [dict setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",distance]   forKey:@"distance"];
        [_routes addObject:dict];
        // add distance to total distance.
        self.pramDistance += distance;
    }

}
```

Once user finishes walking/running I draw rout of walk/run on map view. For this purpose I simply draw a ploy line over MKMapView using all the recorded locations.

The map view shows zig-zag line for route and distance is always incorrect. Please suggest me where I am doing wrong and what should I amend to make it work proper?

Here is the comparison (left one is other's app and right one is mine):
[image: Comparison of other app and my app]

Comment: The interface of what I see, at the moment, isn't attractive enough for me to want to use your app. Rather you find that out now, then after a couple of months of no activity on your hard work.

Comment: Are you just calculating distance "as the crow flies"?

Comment: @CarlVeazey I just need to record total distance and locations to show them on the map.

Comment: So are you actually measuring the individual legs? Or just straight line distance? I don't understand your variable naming so am not totally sure what's going on.

Comment: @CarlVeazey I am actually measuring every step and want it to be most accurate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though I didn't get much of the help here, I found some help and idea in this question: [Corelocation incorrect distances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3093919/corelocation-incorrect-distances)

What I did to fix the problem is:

- I stored recent 5 locations in an array.
- Once 5 items are stored in the array, I checked for the nearest location.
- After getting nearest location I calculated distance between last best location and stored new location in last best location.

P.S.: My code is messy and naming conventions are not that generic, that's why I am not posting my code here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

Import CLLocationManagerDelegate,

```
 CLLocation *currentLocation = self.currentLocation;
       float distanceMile = [currentLocation distanceFromLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]]/1609.34;

    -(void)postCurrentLocationOfDevice
    {

        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    }
    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
    {
       self.currentLocation = [locations objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];

    }

    -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
    {
        self.currentLocation = newLocation;
        [self.locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for quick response. But I need frequent update of location to keep track of route user covered. So stopping it will not solve my purpose. Also I need distance in meters.